# Animation of a person sitting down

Tags: animation, import

i am quite new to blender.
i have a person which should sit down to a "chair".
The Person is rigged (has bones and so on)[image: Rigged Person should sit down to Chair] but if i go into animate and move the bones (and the person object) and insert frames, it doesen't move at all. It always shows the last pose.

Comment: okay, i edited it. sorry

Comment: or do i have to something else in the beginning of the animation? did i forget anything?

Answer (score 1):

okay i found the problem.
in the bottom toolbox "Scaling" was selected for the keyframe insert...

Comment: If you are happy with your solution, it's good to mark your question as answered